# Sencha touch vs Ionic framework pros & cons

Tags: ionic-framework, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am Phonegap/Cordova developer, I plan to move to new technology. I am a little bit confuse that which is best for mobile application development and why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Really, it depends on what your application requirements are. From my experience, if your application requires a lot of hardware resources, don't use cross platform options, not even [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com/). I would use native approach in that kind scenario. If your application is a lot like a mobile friendly web application and you are pressed by deadline, I would recommend using Hybrid approaches. Within hybrid approaches I would say use ionic for the following reasons.

Welcome to the Ionic World!

- Free, Open Source, Constantly growing and Great documentations
- Its on top of cordova. So you will have access to hundred of cordova plugins to achieve native functionality, i.e. access to native APIs.
- The power on AngularJS comes built in with the framework.
- Touch Optimized UI, [removes normal 300 ms delay from webview on touch](http://blog.ionic.io/hybrid-apps-and-the-curse-of-the-300ms-delay/)!
- MV* Pattern
- Built in CSS components and Ionicons
- ~ 100% code share
- Cloud app reports
- No special SDK required
- Available from NPM
- Great with testing
- Scalable

Check Ionic [Showcase](http://showcase.ionicframework.com/) for the top apps built on Ionic.

Check [Ionic vs other contenders](http://stackshare.io/stackups/xamarin-vs-phonegap-vs-ionic).

PS, I haven't spent time on Sencha and its mainly commercial. I could not find its source code on Github. Sorry Sencha!

Both Ionic and Sencha run on Cordova but seriously, Ionic has done terrific job and I would recomment it anyday.

**UPDATE**

*Check out [NativeScript](http://www.telerik.com/nativescript) and [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/). Both of them deliver native UI rendering (unlike Ionic and Sencha) and look promising. They are also backed by Telerik and Facebook with React being one of the most starred repo on Github. Check [this](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/11/nativescript-vs-ionic-framework-should-you-switch/) article by Nic Raboy.*

Comment: There's a GPL release of Sencha Touch and Ext JS. Sencha Touch's commercial version is also free.

Comment: For the unaware, GPL requires that your app also be GPL and your source open.